# Are parallel queries with mysqlnd actually possible?

Tags: mysql, parallelism

So I have been playing with asynchronous database requests in PHP using mysqlnd in an attempt to achieve parallel database requests and cut down total execution time i.e. rather than:

```
total time = query 1 time + query 2 time + query 3 time + query 4 time
```

instead:

```
total time = max(query 1 time, query 2 time, query 3 time, query 4 time)
```

My thinking is that using `MYSQLI_ASYNC` makes the query non blocking allowing you to kick of a number of queries right after another with a new connection, and as MySQL handles queries in parallel natively, thus achieve execution of parallel database requests.  I am however seeing absolutely no improvement in execution time whatsoever and instead am seeing the same execution time as if the queries are run one after the other.

Where am I going wrong and is this actually possible?  (note I am a developer not a sysadmin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically after some more research my conclusion is that parallel queries are just not possible with MySQL at all. The closest it looks like you can get is by using shard-query, but I believe this can only execute parallel queries against a single database when using partitioning, and partitioning does not support foreign keys.  Foreign keys are a massive part of the database structure in Magento so this just isn't an option.

Hopefully one day parallel queries will be supported but for now, back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you work on speeding up each query. Parallel execution in PHP, especially on Windows, is mostly a myth.

[Better evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866366/php-mysqli-asynchronous-queries-with)

Comment: So queries can still only be executed in series by the MySQL server?  How very disappointing....  Whilst the evidence does seem to support this, any technical documentation that you are aware of to back this up?  Unfortunately speeding up each query isn't really an option, but I'll have a think about it.

Comment: The docs seem to leave out that you need to have multiple connections to get parallelism.  For simple queries, the burden of connect+disconnect is likely to be worse.

Comment: Ah right, so with a new connection, MySQL will execute queries in parallel?  These are potentially pretty large queries so it might not be an issue.

Comment: I have not tried, but I suspect the `ASYNC` api would work only with one connection per one async thread.  "Pretty large queries" -- If this is designed for a user interface, rethink the design.

Comment: Would you care to show us the "pretty large queries"?

Comment: This is actually working with Magento, so the design is not really up to me, basically looking at ways to improve to the speed which data is collected in relation to 'collections'.  So we are talking about all kinds of queries across all kinds of tables of varying sizes.  I think I'll do a bit more experimentation as it still sounds possible a solution is in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Consider tossing several queries into a **Stored Procedure**.  That way, single `CALL` to it is a single round trip to the server.  For `localhost` this does not matter much.  But if the app and MySQL are separate machines, and especially if they could be on separate sides of the continent, then bundling the queries together this way can be a significant speedup.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE primary_key = 123;
```

is so fast that parallelism is useless.

Scanning a million rows to find 10 is so slow that you should change the query design, independent of parallelism.

I have web pages that need to run a few dozen trivial or simple queries; the page response time is good enough that I don't feel the need for parallelism.  If the page gets slow, I look for the slowest query and focus on how to improve it.